# Using ZCTA (Census ZipCode) polygones

Tags: geojson, census

I have downloaded some files from census website and did some cleaning to get ZCTA map for New York, but I noticed that there are overlapped regions (some regions are inside others). For some statistical purposes, It needs to be isolated. I looked online for some answers but I couldn't find a convenient answer to this.

I ended up producing file similar to this one:
http://catalog.opendata.city/dataset/nyc-zip-code-tabulation-areas/resource/eec14f19-9794-46ef-9bf4-7f6835ffbf4c

If search "Manhattan"; you will see these small squares inside big ones.

Can anyone who has experience with GIS explain why ? Is it problem related to drawing polygons or it's really overlapped.

Comment: your link is coming up dead for me

Answer (score 0):

I've translated most of Census' Cartography files to GeoJSON and made them available here:

https://github.com/loganpowell/census-geojson